# Let x be any non zero real number. Show that $x^8-x^5-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^4}\ge0$

Tags: inequality

Let x be any non zero real number.Show that

$x^8-x^5-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^4}\ge0$

This question is from the Regional Olympiad Materials.This is  trivial proof, but I am stuck designing the equation. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: **Hint:** Multiply with $x^4$, and then let $t=x^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $x^4 > 0$ for all non-zero real $x$, the inequality is equivalent to $x^{12} - x^9 - x^3 + 1 \geq 0$, or $u^4 - u^3 - u + 1 \geq 0$, where $u = x^3$.

Now $$u^4 - u^3 - u + 1 = (u - 1)(u^3 - 1) = (u-1)^2(u^2 + u + 1) = (u-1)^2\left(\left(u+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}\right) \geq 0$$ which is true.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}$. Then:
$$x^8-x^5-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^4} = x^2\left(y^2-y-2\right)$$
can be negative only if $y\in(-1,2)$. But the AM-GM inequality gives that if $x>0$, then $y>2$, and if $x<0$, then $y<-2$, hence the claim follows.

Answer (score 3):

$\text{LHS} = x^5\left(x^3-1\right) - \dfrac{x^3-1}{x^4} = \left(x^3-1\right)\left(x^5-\dfrac{1}{x^4}\right) = \dfrac{(x^3-1)(x^9-1)}{x^4} = \dfrac{(x^3-1)^2\left(x^6+ x^3+1\right)}{x^4} = \dfrac{\left(x^3-1\right)^2}{x^4}\left(\left(x^3+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{3}{4}\right) \geq 0$.